# Conflict with leaflet-markercluster-rails and another gem?

Tags: leaflet

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of some sort of conflict between leaflet-markercluster-rails and another gem that would prevent the markers from displaying properly?

It's the only thing I can think after almost a week for messing around with code.  NOTHING seems to work.  See [my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/66659843?noredirect=1) for my code.

I'm running rails 4.2.5 on Windows box if that mattes.  ANY help would be wonderful. :)

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, it turned out that the gems *leaflet-rails* and *leaflet-markercluster-rails* were not compatible.

using different gems, I was able to get not only the most up to date versions, but they were compatible.

```
gem 'rails-assets-leaflet', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-leaflet.markercluster', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
```

Hope this helps somebody else not loose days of their life trying to get things to work. :)